# Codemagic iOS build fails due to firebase GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, codemagic

I am building my flutter project with codemagic for iOS.
The android build works as expexted.
The iOS build error:

```
    Xcode build done.                                           1520.2s
    
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    Xcode's output:
    
    [...]

    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.



Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

However my ios/Runner contains the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

I have also tried to create environment variables to store this file without success.

I am stuck at this point, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the build system expects it to be located at /Users/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved the problem!
As @Paul Beusterien mentioned, the build system  expects the file to be located at /Users/Downloads/GoogleServices-Info.plist.

How to change that?

Two possible solutions:

1. If you have Xcode:
   Simply click on the file and use the file inspector to change the location of the path to "Relative to project".

2.Without using Xcode:
Go into your project.pbxproj file and look for name="GoogleServices-Info.plist" path="..." and change that path to just "GoogleServices-Info.plist", if the file is in your ios/Runner/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your project.pbxproj file and look for name="GoogleServices-Info.plist" path="..." and Delete that line, now push to your git branch and run the build on codemagic